# document.createElement('OPTION') not show in source IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I feel silly asking this...but

I have a function `function addOpts(val, ddl ){....}` that adds items to a list box control from a `ajaxRequest.responseXML`

The problem is that the items are added to my control on the webpage and works fine , but when I look at the page source it only shows my default index "All.." which is coded in the code behind.

Showing:

```
<select name="ddl" id="ddl" multiple="multiple"> <option value="">All..</option>
```

Looking for in source:

```
 <select name="ddl" id="ddl" multiple="multiple">
       <option value="">All..</option>
       <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
       <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
    </select>
```

Am I missing state change or postback or someting, because I need that option value to build a search string for item looking

Comment: What source are you looking at? Like "Right Click" -> "View Page Source"? Or are you looking in Developer Tools? If you use "View Page Source", that doesn't show dynamic changes to your page - it shows the original page/HTML served. If you're using Developer Tools, make sure you hit the little refresh button because it doesn't automatically show updates

Comment: This is normal behavior, if you look at page source with Ctrl+U, the source is not dynamic. Use Developer Tool for actual HTML.

Comment: View source will always show the code the original page request that was delivered to the browser. If you want to see the changes made by JavaScript you'll need to check the console/developer tools.

Comment: The source I'm looking at..is the developer tools that comes with IE 8.0.6001

Comment: @ChadSellers Then hit the little "Refresh" button, because changes are not automatically updated.